# Cross update taking values from another column based on duplicates found in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table_A containing duplicate records in column ID,but has distinct E_ID for each duplicate ID.I have retrieved records using below mention query.

```
select ID,E_ID,Comments
from table_A
where ID in (SELECT ID
                FROM table_A t where ID !=' '
                GROUP BY ID 
                HAVING COUNT(distinct E_ID) > 1
               )
group by ID,E_ID,Comments order by ID
```

This query will give me output like this

```
 ID |  E_ID   | Comments
11101   | 55237 | Null
11101   | 15243 | Null
11103   | 55249 | Null
11103   | 15286 | Null
11107   | 55255 | Null
11107   | 15290 | Null
```

Now i want to UPDATE Comments column which will give me output like below shown table.
Note:please look into comments sentences carefully,you see E_ID differences

```
ID  |  E_ID         | Comments
11101   |  55237    | Duplicate of E_ID 15243
11101   |  15243    | Duplicate of E_ID 55237
11103   |  55249    | Duplicate of E_ID 15286
11103   |  15286    | Duplicate of E_ID 55249
11107   |  55255    | Duplicate of E_ID 15290
11107   |  15290    | Duplicate of E_ID 55255
```

You could see that E_IDs are cross update in Comments column for each duplicate ID.
I need a update Query to achieve this,Please help.
I really don't know how to tile this.

Comment: are there only ever two rows with the same id, or can there be more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `outer apply` query to generate a list of duplicates.  This will work even if there is more than one duplicate:

```
update  org
set     Comments = 'Duplicate of E_ID ' + stuff(dup.lst, 1, 2, '')
from    TableA org
outer apply
        (
        select  ', ' + cast(dup.E_ID as varchar) as [text()]
        from    TableA dup
        where   dup.ID = org.ID
                and dup.E_ID <> org.E_ID
        for xml path('')
        ) dup(lst);
```

I'll add an SQL Fiddle example when it's back up (right now it's showing `datasource [sqlfiddle] doesn't exist`.)

Comment: This works fine but when ID column has NULL values it updates that column too.. anyway thanks...Gud job

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this ( can't check it at the moment so appologies for any typos)

```
update tablea
set comments=comment from 
(
  select a.id,a.e_id, 'Duplicate of E_ID '+convert(varchar(10),b.e_id) comment
  from tablea a join tablea b
  on a.id=b.id and a.e_id <> b.e_id 
) x 
where tablea.id = x.id and tablea.e_id= x.e_id
```